# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher_assist:compileProfileAidl'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart

When I run `flutter build apk --debug` or `flutter build apk --release` or `flutter run` it throws error

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':Some dependency<here,launcher_assist>:compileProfileAidl'
```

with `Failed to install the following SDK components:
    platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
The SDK directory is not writable` though my android SDK platform is 28

please help.Thanks

flutter doctor -v:

[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-1.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.19.0-1.0.pre at
      C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Flutter\flutter_windows_1.17.0-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision 3519bec6c4 (3 weeks ago), 2020-05-08 00:34:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 3953c3ccd1
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-5.0.dev 4da5b40fb6)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: run `flutter doctor` and share the output

Comment: I did it.Please look to it

Comment: install android studio. it is reqired.

Comment: I tried that but it too throws 'unknown error'

Comment: Follow [installation steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) in the sequence mentioned on flutter site. Those are proper you wont get issues.

Comment: did everything but nothing works

Comment: Check if you have java installed before installing android studio. 
Install the latest version of Android studio. 
 Use stable version **Flutter 1.17**

Comment: i think i have problem with gradle or dependency

Comment: not all dependencies show this error that means my flutter is alright

Comment: if i remove this dependency then  it works fine

Comment: It is mentioned in the installation guide, Android studio is required for providing dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: The Problem occured was mismatching of the versions of tools used in SDK
Solution: Download Android Studio and use it's SDK manager to download or update or replace  stuffs **Automatically** not custom